# Converting guitar tabs to piano chords, song doesn't sound the same?

Tags: guitar, piano, chords

I play the piano, and I'm still a noob at it. There's this song I really want to learn, but when I convert the guitar tabs into piano chords, the chords are hard to switch and doesn't really sound the same.

**Guitar tabs**

```
E|--------------------0h2--|
B|-----------1--------3----|
G|--0--------0--------2----|
D|--0--------0h2------0----|
A|--0h2------3-------------|
E|--3----------------------|
```

**Converted Piano Chords**

```
4||-----------c--------e-F--|-
4||--------------------d----|-
3||--g--------g-e------a----|-
3||--d--------d--------d----|-
3||-----------c-------------|-
2||--a-b--------------------|-
2||--g----------------------|-
```

Is the conversion correct? I assumed numbers on the left in the piano chords represent the octave.

P. S. The song is In April - Jhonny Flynn

Comment: Second chord should be d to e not g to e and the third one the F should be F#.

Comment: The chords will be G, C and D, all going sus 2 to major. It may sound better up an octave on piano.

Answer (score 1):

The version I listened to is in B, using B, E and F#. The sus2 on the F# is under, not on top as in that tab version. So it's not going to sound the same. Tab is notorious for being inaccurate (at least in my opinion!), so this version is likely a simplified one. It will sort of work on guitar with a capo (on fret 4), but still won't be a faithful copy of the original.

Edit - It looks like the 'e-chords' version, which states capo on 4, which may have escaped you.

Edit  - the 'D' part is a 6 / 5, rather than what the tab says.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the main chords I need to play are  B, E and F#? Could you give me an idea of what sus is? I'm sorry, but I had very little piano training, and not aware of the intermediate concepts.

Comment: "A suspended chord (sus chord) is a musical chord in which the (major or minor) third is omitted, replaced usually with either a perfect fourth (About this sound play (help·info)) or a major second (About this sound play (help·info)),[1] although the fourth is far more common. The lack of a minor or a major third in the chord creates an open sound, while the dissonance between the fourth and fifth or second and root creates tension."  - Wikipedia